# drag and drop from one cdkDropList to another

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

So I've got a list of items that I want to be able to drag onto a node of a chart and fire an event. I'm using the cdk DragDropModule and here is my code:

list.component.html

```
<div class="card" cdkDropList #thisList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[thatList]">
    <div *ngFor=let item of items">
        <label cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="item">{{item.name}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

chartNode.component.html

```
<div cdkDropList #thatList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[thisList]" (cdkDropListDropped)="someFn($event)">
    <div> potentially other chartNodes go here </div>
</div>
```

chartNode.component.ts

```
someFn(event: any): void {
    console.log(event);
}
```

My question is: why isn't `someFn` getting called?

Comment: If you remove this code  [cdkDragData]="item" does it work?  I think the item is implicitly known due to the *ngFor statement.

Comment: nope, that doesn't do it. Is it possible that having nested #thatList declarations is causing some sort of issue? My chartNode component often contains other chartNodes.

Although, I've tried putting the cdkDropList on the parent component of the chartNodes and that didn't do the trick either